# rewriting rules end up with 'page not found' on https pages

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, https

I have multiple rewriting rules like the one below on my site

```
 ^product/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ /index.php?action=product&category=$1&type=$2
```

I also have self-signed ssl certificate installed and few pages on which php redirects to https. When I'm on such https page and click a link that matches above rewriting rules, I end up on 'Not Found' error page

How to tell apache that all rewriting rules should be read relatively to http, not https?

EDIT:
I sorted it out by adding copy of rewriting rules under :443 Virtual Host

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Apache serves HTTPS on the standard port, you could add a conditional before the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ...
```

**EDIT:** There's another variable, you could check (and it's in the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), too):

> `HTTPS`
>
> Will contain the text "on" if the connection is using SSL/TLS, or "off" otherwise. (This variable can be safely used regardless of whether or not mod_ssl is loaded).

So this should be better, regardless on which port SSL is delivered:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ...
```

Comment: neither RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off nor RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443 help. I'm still getting 'not found' when hitting eg [https]://product/jewellery/rings

Comment: Hm. Then you'll need to post your entire rule-set. There might be something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
```

Have a look at [htaccess HTTPS / SSL Tips, Tricks, and Hacks](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/ssl-example-usage-in-htaccess.html)